# Improve efficiency of this filtering function

Tags: ios, swift

I have a (potentially very large) array of `users`. I want to remove a specific user from this array, if the user is contained within it. Here is my code:

```
if users.contains(user) {
  users = users.filter { $0.id != user.id }
  count -= 1
  change -= 1
}
```

Thinking about this in terms of time and space complexity, `contains()` is a O(n) operation, and `filter()` is also a O(n) operation.

I could do this:

```
for (index, user) in users.enumerated() {
  if user == userToRemove {
    users.remove(at: index)
    count -= 1
    change -= 1
  }
}
```

But here `remove(at:)` is a O(n) operation, as is the for-loop. So in both cases, I'm having to loop through the whole array twice.

Another thing I could do is convert it to a `Set` beforehand, but that would the lose the ordering.

Is there any way to improve on the efficiency of this such that it only has to loop through at most once?

Comment: `removeAll(where:)` is also too much complex? `users.removeAll(where: { $0 == userToRemove })`? Or if you want to remove only one user (there is unicity in your case), you could use `firstIndex(where:)`, and `remove(at:)` instead of looping all the `users` with `for ... .enumerated() {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want unique users, you could just use a `Set`, whose `contains` is O(1).

If you need the users to be ordered, you can use `OrderedSet` from the [Swift Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedSet.md) package.

Comment: Yeah they need to be ordered, I'll look into that `OrderedSet`